# iOS: getting values from valueForKeyPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

i'm using IBAForms to create a simple form for my project and i've achieved almost everything except for getting the values from de fields. I have this code:

```
    NSLog(@"SUBMIT");
id values = [[self formDataSource] modelValueForKeyPath:@"diabetePickListItem"];
for (id key in values){
    id values = [values objectForKey:key];

    NSString *keyString = (NSString *)key;
    NSLog(@"%@",keyString);
    NSString *valueString = (NSString *)values;
    NSLog(@"%@",valueString);
}

NSLog(@"diabetes %@", values);
```

and it gives me this ouput in the console:

```
2012-10-07 07:02:37.145 BigBlueTest[64483:10403] SUBMIT
2012-10-07 07:02:37.147 BigBlueTest[64483:10403] Yes
2012-10-07 07:02:37.148 BigBlueTest[64483:10403] (null)
2012-10-07 07:02:37.150 BigBlueTest[64483:10403] diabetes {(
Yes
)}
```

What i do not understand is how i can get the key out of the values that is returned from the modelValueForKeyPath method. I just want to get that 'Yes' or 'No' value without doing the fast enumeration. I really don't know what i'm missing in this code. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The problem is that when i try to use objectAtIndex it gives me -[__NSCFSet objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error. The applicacion i'm working on contains a form to collect simple information, if i fill the form completely and print the content of the values i get this output:

```
NSLog(@"%@",_formValues);

2012-10-08 11:27:48.524 BigBlueTest[17285:10403] {
    activityPickListItem = "{(\n    Running/jogging\n)}";
    bloodAfter = 60;
    bloodBefore = 58;
    diabetePickListItem = "{(\n    Yes\n)}";
    durationPickListItem = "{(\n    10 or less\n)}";
    intensityPickListItem = "{(\n    Moderate\n)}";
    lowGlucoseSyntom = "{(\n    No\n)}";
    pickInsulinUse = "{(\n    Yes\n)}";
    pickMeasureUnit = "{(\n    mmol/L\n)}";
    recentMealPickListItem = "{(\n    30 minutes ago\n)}";
}
```

If i use valueForKeypath then i get the value in this format {(value)}. I haven't figured out a way to get the string value out of it. Tried methods from NSDictionary and NSArray unsuccessfully. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a veteran in Objective C, but shouldn't values be an array? And the problem seems to have to do with the typecast statement "`(NSString *)values`", which looks really uncommon and a bit wrong. I think you should convert values in a `NSString` with a different approach, because it seems to return `NULL`. Maybe you could try something like 
`NSString *valueString = [NSString stringWithString:[values objectAtIndex:yourIndex]` (or use a `NSRange` for more objects)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with IBAForms but it looks like values is giving you a collection.  I would suggest that you set a breakpoint right after the line id values... and look at what is being returned into values.  Sometimes the context sensitive tool tips don't work in XCode.  In that case you can type `po values` in the debug window.  That should give you a better idea what you are dealing with.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me a lot in finding info about what is happening. However i haven't managed to get just the value. It baffles me that i can't find a way to get just de value in here: {(value)}. objectAtIndex doesn't work. values is id type.

Comment: Try this: BOOL answer = [[values objectAtIndex:0] boolValue]];